# How Do You Launch A Specific ViewController When UILocalNotification Is Clicked In Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am firing UILocalNotifications in Swift and that is working fine. However, when I click the notification it opens my app like it normally would (to the default ViewController). How do I make it open a specific ViewController instead?

Answer (score 0):

For handling the notification, the application in AppDelegate should be overwritten.

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)